# What does "WBCI SSR" stand for?

Tags: air-travel, terminology

What does *WBCI Special Service Request* on a boarding pass stand for?

I see that code on boarding passes for a lot of airlines I'm flying—JAL, LOT, LH—but couldn't find the code explained online.

Comment: Did you check-in online?

Comment: I see that code on a lot of airlines I'm flying. JAL, LOT, LH, and others.

Comment: Yes, I checked-in online.

Comment: I think this SSR will be added after you check-in online to mark your record. WBCI I guess it stands for Web Check-in

Answer (score 2):

WBCI = Web Based [Check In | Customer Interaction], depending on how long person has been in the industry.

Evidence: hard to find online, but here's an out of date example that Tiger uses it for web checkin:

[image]

Second evidence: https://www.acronymfinder.com/WBCI.html